# Verizon message+ does not sync your own texts with iphone texts

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

My friends are using Verizon's Message+ app for a group chat.  I would like to participate.

The primary problem is that when I send messages from Message+, the messages that *I* send do not show up as text messages in the iPhone iMessage version of the conversation.  So I can only see what I text from the Message+ app.

Everyone else can see my messages in both places.  I cannot find anything in the iPhone settings to change this.

[This problem makes no sense... why would the app not sync my own messages with my own phone, when it shows it to everyone else, even though some people don't have iPhones (some are on android)? ] (Original)

Edited: Everyone else can see their own texts in both apps, but I cannot.  There must be some setting to toggle this, but I cannot find it in either app's settings.  None of my friends toggled any settings from default, nor did I.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Further, I would just use the iphone imessage version of the conversation and ignore the Verizon version, but the imessage conversation keeps deleting people's names and just showing phone numbers in the group chat *randomly*, and this just makes trying to follow along confusing.

Comment: I will also say that I tried reinstalling the app and this did not change the problem.  I also tried hard rebooting my iPhone and this did not change the problem.

Comment: I suppose this could be a problem specific to the iPhone SE, which I have.  I believe I am the only one that has one.

Answer (score 0):

Ask Verizon why *their* app does not have some feature you think it should have.

Re why you think it's strange that the *recipient* sees the message in both apps... what else did you expect to happen?  Verizon's Message+ does not implement a different communication channel, it's a received SMS.  Of course both are going to show it, they'd be useless if they did not.

Comment: That's just my point.  You say "of course both will show it".  But they don't.  Not for my own messages.  Other people in the group, by the way, also see their own text messages they send in both apps regardless of which app they send it in.  It is only my own phone that will not do this.  That's why I asked the question - there must be some setting, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Let me reiterate in case it was missed: when other people send a text from either message+ or imessage, they see their text in both apps.  But not for me.  My question above about it making no sense was not clear.

Comment: I will further comment that I did try asking the Verizon support forum community and I get internal server error messages when trying to post... so its down.  Which was why I came here.

Comment: YOUR phone will not show it in the Messages app.  Why would it?  It was not sent with the Messages app.  Those who RECEIVE it, however, have two different apps listening to the same communications channel, so both apps show the message.

Comment: Marc, I do appreciate your response.  My friends are saying their own texts do show in their iMessages app when they send them by the Verizon app.  But I agree with your logic - one would think it would not.  So they are saying the send channels are in fact linked.  I'm not talking about receiving a message.

Comment: Since they were saying it was working, I assumed that I must have some setting wrong.